# IE7 filter cuts of element

Tags: filter, internet-explorer-7, overflow

I have an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dnHVB/1/

In IE7 filter on parent causes my inner element to get cut of like its set overflow hidden on parent.

Is there a way around this?

Thank you!

Comment: I've found this bug too. It happened when I was using filter for creating the gradient on dropdown menu.